# Должны ли мы для русскоязычного читателя сохранять сербское название реки - Рашка?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

*[Рашка, иногда Ратина, Расиня (серб. Рашка) — несудоходная река в Сербии.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0))*

Мне, как и моим классовым врагам, не нравится слово "Рашка".

[Как "Рашка" взбудоражила госпатриотов](https://www.kavkazr.com/a/chem-ne-ugodila-blogeram-doch-chechenskogo-milliardera/28076498.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не вижу причин изменять географическое название, оказывая ненужную честь воинственно-косноязычным меньшинствам фактическим признанием элементов их языка, - да мало ли как ещё у них может повернуться одноимённый орган! Ставить их представителей на место нужно преподаванием основ географии или топонимики. Когда в разговоре со мной пытаются Васильевский остров назвать "Васькой", продолжить разговор я могу только о здоровье кота. В нашем случае можно поинтересоваться, с чего это их в Сербию заносит.